# MVC: How to bind array in hidden form field value to model collection property

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have saved a collection of ints in a hidden field using JQuery (this is a collection of pkids's that I use to store data across several pages).

In my ViewModel I have the property:

```
public IEnumerable<int> SubGroupPkids { get; set; }
```

in my View I have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="CheckedSubGroups" value="[]" />
```

The Save button on my form uses JQuery to serialize and post the info back to the controller:

```
var $form = $(self.options.pushFormId);
            if (!$form.valid())
                return;
            var data = $form.serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: $form.prop('method'),
                url: $form.prop('action'),
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    showPushDialog(data);
                },
            });
```

The Post method of the collection has the signature

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PushPurchaser([Bind]PushPurchaserViewModel model)
```

So as it stands I need to save the collection of ints that I have on my form as the collection of ints that I have in my model so that it can be bound to the model that I can then use in the controller post method. I'm not quite sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Razor`, you could add `Hidden` fields in your form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.SubGroupPkids.Count; i++ )    
{
  @Html.Hidden("SubGroupPkids[" + i + "]", Model.SubGroupPkids[i])
}
```

And change `public IEnumerable<int> SubGroupPkids { get; set; }`
to

```
public List<int> SubGroupPkids { get; set; }
```

You can change their value using `JQuery`,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="SubGroupPkids[0]"]').val(5);
 });
```

Comment: Why did you change IEnumerable to a List?

Comment: @matt_lethargic, to apply indexing